# How to reduce the clothesline-effect in ST_Transform?

Tags: transform

When we use [standard **ST_Transform**](https://www.sis.se/api/document/preview/616067/) (e.g. [PostGIS implementation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html)), from a SRID to another that curves straight lines, **the original straight lines represented by two points, that must be transformed into curves,  will be transformed into straight lines**. This is the central problem.

Illustrating below a real-life example (from an equal-area projection to WGS84), a grid transformation, where the large cell, after transform, loses compatibility with the small cells.

[image]

I don't know if the problem already had an appropriate name, but everyone knows the curve made by the line of a clothesline supported between two points, and they know that tightening it, it will be a straight line.

[image]

The set of original straight lines are like a *tight clothesline*: if the *ST_Transform* is made with more points (e.g. by [*ST_Segmentize*](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Segmentize.html)) it results in a correct transformation, analog to a *loose  clothesline*.

[Theorem] When not good, that is, when ST_Transform results are bad:
the central distance ***d*** (illustrated) between "correct line" and "bad line" **is proportional to** the length of **the original line**. 
So, seems that a "good segmentization procedure" must use two reasonable assumptions:

- the optimal split is into the middle (where *d* is maximum);
- the length of the segments must be a fraction of  the "characteristic diameter" (*cdiam*)  of the geometry that will be transformed.

[The question] **How to do "good segmentization"?**  If the hypotheses are correct, we have three **problems**:

1. **more segments is more cost**: more CPU time and more "pollution" (more points and geometrical complexity), we need a balance between quality and complexity.
2. **segmentize is not necessary** in some directions: in general a direction (for example lines parallel to longitude) not need to be segmentized.
3. **aleatory segmentization is not good**: the "split into segments" process must to use (the optimal) **middle point**.

... A naive solution is to use a fraction of *cdiam* as parameter in *ST_Segmentize*.

---

### A clue but not the optimal solution

This example was expressed in PostGIS, but is only an illustration, the ideia is to segmentize by "characteristic diameter".

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION ST_Transform_resilient(
  g geometry,
  srid integer,
  density float DEFAULT 0.05
) RETURNS geometry AS $f$
  SELECT CASE
    WHEN isnot_point THEN -- using the fraction of cdiam here:
          ST_Transform(  ST_Segmentize(g,density*(a+p)/2.0)  ,srid)
    ELSE  ST_Transform(g,srid)
    END
  FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN is_poly THEN SQRT(ST_Area(g))
                ELSE 0 END,
           CASE WHEN is_poly THEN ST_Perimeter(g)/3.5
                WHEN isnot_point THEN 2.0*ST_Length(g) END,
           isnot_point
    FROM ( SELECT GeometryType(g) ) t1(geomtype), LATERAL (
      SELECT
         CASE WHEN geomtype='POLYGON' OR geomtype='MULTIPOLYGON' THEN true ELSE false END AS is_poly,
         CASE WHEN geomtype='POINT'   OR geomtype='MULTIPOINT'   THEN false ELSE true END AS isnot_point
    ) t2
  ) t3(a,p,isnot_point)
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

PS: a final correction is possible by minimal ST_Simplify, to remove collinear points. I need an optimal solution, one that generates good geometries with less complexity, and uses less CPU time to do so... And, ideally, understands the directions that really need ST_Segmentize.

Comment: I think that you have expressed the answer yourself. Using ST_Segmentize with a segment length that is based on trial and error is probably that most users do.

Comment: Thanks @user30184, but I need an **optimal solution**, one that generates good geometries with less complexity, and uses less CPU time to do so... And, ideally, understands the directions that really need ST_Segmentize.

Comment: For curved linestrings you will need additional vertices. For knowing the minimal number of vertices that is needed for getting an acceptable result there could perhaps be an iterative function: create the straight line and then take a point from x units from the starting point of the original linestring and transform it. Compute the distance between the line made with the "tight" method and this new point. Is is within acceptable tolerance? If not, transform a new point that is either closer or farther to the start point and find a value for the segment length to me used with ST_Segmentize.

Comment: Have you already made some tests about how much CPU is needed for using ST_Segmentize + ST_Transform with a short segment length + ST_Simplify compared to running ST_Segmentize + ST_Transform with a segment length that is known to be optimal? It would be interesting to see the results.

Comment: I dare say, this is a moot endeavor. Projections are inherently wrong - technically, EPSG:4326 itself is not even a projection - and imprinting geoidal curvature into planar space impossible. If you need to preserve planar topology for planar spatial relations in between transformations, work with vertices only and derive/construct any higher dim geometries directly from them, much like in a classic node/edge topology definition.

Comment: @geozelot I'm careful with my data sources, generally keeping the original raw data "as is" and using minimal or no transformation. For data-interchange, for example to publish the data in standard  GeoJSON polygons or [Geo URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme) points, we need a "to EPSG:4326" transform... So, I don't get your point. This question is about a "math problem", that occours in any projection transformation (and for any X projection, "from X to WGS84" is a valid transformation).